# Php Mysqli not updating data in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Here is my code, it works and no errors pop up and the correct data for the variables are there.

When it's all done it shows Done for the last echo.

However, when I go into `heidisql` to view the database table, nothing has changed, even when I run the query in `heidisql`, still same results.

```
// Make connection to database
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbnm);
// Make query
$myQuery = "
    UPDATE Ekhaya_Inventory SET 
        ekhaya_inventory_stock_item = '" . $stockItemPost . "',
        ekhaya_inventory_stock_left = '" . $stockLeftPost . "',
        ekhaya_inventory_stock_out = '" . $stockOutPost . "',
        ekhaya_inventory_stock_minimum = '" . $stockMinimumPost . "',
        ekhaya_inventory_stock_price_per_item = '" . $stockPricePIPost . "',
        ekhaya_inventory_value_of_stock_left = '" . $stockValueOfStockLeftPost . "' 

        WHERE
            ekhaya_inventory_stock_code = '" . $stockCodePost . "' 
        AND
            ekhaya_inventory_stock_code = '" . $stockLocationPost . "'
";

mysqli_query($connection,$myQuery)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));
mysqli_close($connection)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));
echo "<br>Done";
```

Comment: are you sure  about that `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yeah, you're comparing two different variable in one field? Are you gonna use OR instead?

Comment: Yes because the stock can exist at every shop but i want to sort it to only change stock at shop A and not shop B-Z

Comment: I know it sounds simple, but in your client (HeidiSQL), have you sorted by ID to find out if anything new has been added? I've also run into issues where HeidiSQL would not refresh but the data showed in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ahhh wait the second variable is the same as the first let me try that

Comment: Thanks people i solved it after you pointed it out lol

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
            ekhaya_inventory_stock_code = '" . $stockCodePost . "' 
        AND
            ekhaya_inventory_stock_code = '" . $stockLocationPost . "'
```

it is wrong because one field can`t contain two different values in the same time